# Delete trigger taking long time on production

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, query-optimization

We have trigger to delete Record(`Tools`) which taking very long time to execute on production but its working perfectly normal on staging. please note that both the environment points to azure database. we have created indexes and primary key and foreign key and we have also configured automatic tuning on both the database. both the databases have similar number of records maximum record in one of table is 2500000.

Its taking 45 sec on production and 1.5 sec on stage env.

```
create table #ScenarioTable(ScenarioId bigint PRIMARY KEY)

DELETE FROM PT_ScenarioDetails WHERE ScenarioId in (SELECT ScenarioId FROM #ScenarioTable)
DELETE FROM PT_ScenarioDetails_Bck  WHERE ScenarioId in (SELECT ScenarioId FROM #ScenarioTable)
DELETE FROM PT_FactorTargetScores WHERE ScenarioId in (SELECT ScenarioId FROM #ScenarioTable)
DELETE FROM PT_FactorTargetScores_Bck WHERE ScenarioId in (SELECT ScenarioId FROM #ScenarioTable)
DELETE FROM PT_TargetDesignations WHERE ScenarioId in (SELECT ScenarioId FROM #ScenarioTable)
DELETE FROM PT_TargetDesignations_Bck WHERE ScenarioId in (SELECT ScenarioId FROM #ScenarioTable) 
DELETE FROM PT_TargetScore WHERE ScenarioId in (SELECT ScenarioId FROM #ScenarioTable) 
DELETE FROM PT_TargetScore_Bck WHERE ScenarioId in (SELECT ScenarioId FROM #ScenarioTable)
DELETE FROM PT_Targets WHERE ScenarioId in (SELECT ScenarioId FROM #ScenarioTable)
DELETE FROM PT_Targets_Bck WHERE ScenarioId in (SELECT ScenarioId FROM #ScenarioTable)
DELETE FROM PT_Factors WHERE ToolId = @ToolId
DELETE FROM PT_Factors_Bck WHERE ToolId = @ToolId
DELETE FROM PT_FactorScores WHERE ToolId = @ToolId
DELETE FROM PT_Designations WHERE ToolId = @ToolId
DELETE FROM PT_Categories WHERE ToolId= @ToolId
DELETE FROM SchedualDetails WHERE SchedualId in (SELECT Id FROM SchedualInquirys with(nolock)     WHERE ScenarioId in (SELECT ScenarioId FROM #ScenarioTable))
DELETE FROM SchedualInquirys WHERE ScenarioId in (SELECT ScenarioId FROM #ScenarioTable) and ToolId = @ToolId
DELETE FROM ScenarioTags WHERE ScenarioId in (SELECT ScenarioId FROM #ScenarioTable)
DELETE FROM Scenarios WHERE ScenarioId in (SELECT ScenarioId FROM #ScenarioTable)
DELETE FROM Services_Tools WHERE ToolId = @ToolId
DELETE FROM Tools WHERE ToolId = @ToolId
```

Is there any way to find actual root cause and resolve the issue?

[**PasteThePlan link**](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S142Oy83t)

Comment: Did you check for [blocking](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/reasons-your-query-is-slow-right-now-blocking-blocking-blocking/) or the wait type shown in sys.dm_exec_requests?

Comment: Yes, i have checked blocking and deadlocks and its showing nothing blocking and locking the queries. @AaronBertrand

Comment: So which query is currently running and what is its wait_type? We can't tell from the description in the question, you're going to have to look. Also did you look at the other "Reasons Your Query Is Slow Right Now" posts in the series (there are links at the bottom)? Did you compare the execution plans in staging and production?

Comment: Also another thing to consider in this type of scenario - does it _matter_ how long it takes to eradicate a tool from 20 tables? A user shouldn't have to _wait_ for this to happen, so whether it takes 2 seconds or 4 seconds or 64 seconds shouldn't matter. Consider making the user action to submit the delete to a queue, and a background process handles the delete. Then it's not a problem _every time it runs_, because nobody is staring at a screen waiting for the queue processor, it is only a problem if it causes blocking (which it shouldn't, with the right indexes in place).

Comment: [I blogged about queueing/deferring deletes just yesterday](https://sqlperformance.com/2022/01/columnstore/serializing-deletes-clustered-columnstore), though for different reasons.

Comment: Yes, i have checked execution plan and its look similar. just showing couple of extra index created by azure on production(we have also tried by deleting suggested index). but by deleting index may affect data retrieval. @AaronBertrand. thanks for share the link. will check it out.

Comment: Its taking long time to execute so the application throws wait operation timeout. @AaronBertrand

Comment: Yes, I understand, but I'm asking _why does the application need to wait for the delete to finish_?

Comment: No @AaronBertrand, its actually not. but wondering why there is remarkable performance difference between two envs. in fact prod have higher configuration then staging. and note that its working perfectly fine before a months. then why is it so its a major confusion in my mind.

Comment: We still don't have enough information to help you. You say the plans look "similar" but what does that mean? Lots of plans can look similar on the surface but vastly different when you dig into it. Is there a _specific_ delete you are comparing? Do you even know _which delete is taking longer_?

Comment: Not really related to the question, but if I were you I would remove that `NOLOCK` hint. In all honesty I have never done any reading or testing around using it on a non-target table it a DML statement, but at best it is ignored so pointless having it there, at worst it is actually used and you risk getting dirty reads in your delete. Either way I'd say it is best removed. (Aaron Bertrand has [written about the hint on the target table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3172/avoid-using-nolock-on-sql-server-update-and-delete-statements/]) so may well know the impact in this case too)

Comment: This is not answerable without execution plans and index definitions. You can share plans via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. Otherwise there simply isn't enough info to answer.

Comment: you can take look into execution plan : https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1sVwnH3K  @Charlieface Plan may include many tables but here we are focused on table prefixed with "PT_" only.

Comment: So this is all running inside a trigger? Why are there repeated reads of `SELECT @DeletedCount = COUNT(*) FROM DELETED` that doesn't get you the number of deleted rows *from the most recent `DELETE`*, it gets you the number of rows *that fired the trigger*. It looks to me that your issues are mainly: `#ScenarioTable` needs a primary key, otherwise you are distinct sorting it every time. All foreign keys *must* have an index, this is the main cause of your slowdown. Each time you delete a row that has a foreign key relationship. You can see this eg in the amount of index scans in the deletes

Comment: @Charlieface I am using trigger to maintain audit related information such as modified dates and modified by field. as far as #scenariotable is concern It is temp table filled with PrimaryKey with scenario Table.   INSERT INTO #ScenarioTable(ScenarioId) 
   (SELECT ScenarioId FROM Scenarios with(nolock) WHERE ToolId = @ToolId). did you mean to say i should define primary key in temp table?

Comment: Yes you should `CREATE TABLE #ScenarioTable (ScenarioId int PRIMARY KEY);`

Comment: @Charlieface I have updated temptable with primary key. sharing updated plan. https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S142Oy83t

Comment: OK that does improve things, but you haven't changed anything else: there are still these 3 lines multiple times unnecessarily `SELECT @DeletedCount = COUNT(*) FROM DELETED` `SELECT @InsertCount = COUNT(*) FROM INSERTED` `UPDATE dbo.Scenarios SET ModifiedById = @ModifiedId, ModifiedDate = @ModifiedDate WHERE ScenarioId = @ScenarioId` and you still need to index *every* foreign key. Look at the plan and find all `Left Semi Join`s with an `Index Scan` or `Key Lookup` below it (lower side of join), these are the ones you need to fix.

Comment: @Charlieface - Thanks for deep suggession, I have disabled trigger and enable it back has reduced to around 22 sec. here is the plan https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1yharOnY

Comment: You *still* haven't changed any of the indexing. If you won't take on board my suggestions I can't help you further

Answer (score 0):

You ask *why* production is slower than staging at doing this cleanup work.

Here are possible reasons:

- Production is far more active, and other RDBMS clients are inserting / updating / selecting rows from the tables you're trying to clean up. This will cause your cleanup queries to wait (and will cause other clients to wait while your cleanup queries run).
- Production has far more rows in the tables you're trying to clean up.
- Your temp table has far more rows in it in production than it does in staging.
- You say it's in an SP. In SQL Server the execution plans for stored code are bound at the time they are compiled. It may be that your SP contains an execution plan that has become grossly inefficient as your production system grew. Try redefining your SP with the [WITH RECOMPILE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/recompile-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15#TsqlProcedure) option. That way it will recreate the execution plans every time it runs. That's fine for cleanup work like what you do here.

All this is my guesswork of course. You'll need to troubleshoot this, one DELETE statement at a time. In SSMS -- Microsoft's SQL Server Management Studio -- right-click in a query window, then select Show Actual Execution Plan, then run the query. The execution plan display sometimes recommends a new index to create.

Or you can consider running this in an overnight JOB at a quiet time on your application.

Comment: Might be a locking granularity issue. Try running EXEC sp_lock during the run in production. Might be a case where your production server is locking at the row level while staging is locking at a more granular level - possibly using table locks.  If the number of locks gets up in the 1000s, performance can go down the tubes. If that is the case, you may need to coax SQL into a different lock strategy, possibly by using a TABLOCK hint. Note that this may impact other processes running in parallel.

Comment: I really wouldn't use the `WITH RECOMPILE` option on the stored procedure; after SQL Server 2000 it is much, much, much better to use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` on individual statements. [Background](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options).